# can't launch two device at the same time (hifiberry dac and mcp3008)

Tags: audio, spi, hifiberry

kernel version

```
uname -r
4.1.6+
```

board type

```
gpio -v
gpio version: 2.26
Copyright (c) 2012-2015 Gordon Henderson
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
For details type: gpio -warranty

Raspberry Pi Details:
  Type: Model B+, Revision: 1.2, Memory: 512MB, Maker: Sony
```

hi guys, i'd used  mcp3008 to convert analog signal into python and send the signal into puredata, csound through pyOSC. on the other hand i got a hifiberry dac as my audio interface both of them were using spi device and i follow the thread add `dtparam=spi=on` in `/boot/config.txt` therefore i got

```
ls -al /dev/spi*
crw-rw---T 1 root spi 153, 0 Jan  1  1970 /dev/spidev0.0
crw-rw---T 1 root spi 153, 1 Jan  1  1970 /dev/spidev0.1
```

it seems fine and i can get my interface at the meanwhile

```
 aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: sndrpihifiberry [snd_rpi_hifiberry_dac], device 0: HifiBerry DAC HiFi pcm5102a-hifi-0 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

but when i trying to play wav file on mplayer or pure data the whole system just froze and don't response, so i need to unplug the power and turn it on again. is there any solution to fix this issue?